# How to Write If() function like if $request data match with $user->id

Tags: laravel

How to Write `if()` function like `if $request data match with $user->id`?

I will write like this, but not working:

```
if ($user->id == $request->userid){

}
else {
    return back()->with('alert', 'Referral Info Invalid.');
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a valid problem description. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

if you route has a middle ware ('auth') it should has a user() function to get the current user:

```
if ($user->id == $request->user()->id){

}
```

but if the userId is not belongs to current user and you want it as a request parameter you could use:

```
  if ($user->id == $request->input('userId')){
    
    }
```